# Homepage on Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0

Tags: microsoft-edge, homepage

Is there a way to set the "homepage" on Microsoft Edge to open to a specific web page?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=set+start+page+Edge&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+set+the+homepage+on+Microsoft+Edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Edge, click the three dots in the upper-right to open the menu.
2. Click **Settings**.
3. Under **Open Microsoft Edge with** select **A specific page or pages**.
4. Enter the URL you wish to open as the homepage.

Comment: Thanks!  Not long after I posted my question, I figured out how to do it - exactly as you suggested.

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct so that others with the same question will know that this is the answer they need.

Comment: Thank music2myear.  I did mark your answer as correct, but I don't have enough reputation points for it to count...yet.

Comment: Really? I believe that when you ask a question it does not matter how many points you have, you'll be able to click the checkbox icon next to the answer that best solves the problem: https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: This is the message I received after clicking the up arrow for your answer:

Comment: Here is the message:  "Thanks for the feedback!  This action requires 15 reputation."

Comment: Oh. OK. Is there a checkmark icon perhaps near the up- and down-arrow buttons? The checkmark icon is the "Accept Answer" button.

Comment: Yes, there is a checkmark icon.  I clicked on that!    I'm still new to this, so appreciate the help and guidance. :)

Comment: No worries. The vote buttons are ways to say "thank you" (or express negative responses) and anyone can click those, but only the person who asked the original question sees and can click the Checkmark, which is the "this answer is the correct one" button.